# wordpress y php

Tags: php, wordpress

Hola un saludo a todos,

soy programador en el lenguaje de php acabo de conseguir un trabajo y me dijo el jefe que usan wordpress, ya leei un poco sobre este framework, pero veo que va referenciado al frontend, vi que hay una conexion a mysql pero no veo como hacer un crud por ejemplo en php estoy buscando en la web wordpress y php pero no encuentro videos para aprender.

me podrian explicar un poco mas sobre esto por favor.

disculpas a los moderadores si hice el post mal pero siempre me han ayudado aqui .

Comment: Hay varias posibilidades, todo dependerá de tus conocimientos y también de si el sitio usa frameworks como Thesis o Génesis. Una forma bastante fácil de hacer lo que quieres sería implementando lo que se conoce como _hooks_. [Puedes consultar esto por ejemplo](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-hooks/), lo cual te dará una idea de cómo funciona y abrirá una posible pista para investigar. Con un _hook_ puedes usar fácilmente código PHP dentro de WP, incluyendo accesos a la base de datos de WP o a otra dedicada específicamente al CRUD.

Comment: lo voy a leer gracias , creo que lo estoy enfocando mal este framework ¿wordpress lo utilizan para la creacion de templates? no se como explicarlo pero es como para definir todo el frontend y despues se exporta y se mete dentro de un proyecto php.   ¿estoy mal?

Comment: En realidad Wordpress es un manejador de contenido o CMS. O sea, su función principal es manejar el contenido de un sitio web en general: posts, páginas, menues, widgets, etc. Todo ello gira en torno a una base de datos que se crea con la instalación de Wordpress. Pero, puedes personalizar a tu gusto o incluso manejar contenido dentro o fuera de wordpress usando puro PHP o combinar. O sea, si en tu trabajo usan WP puedes construir tu CRUD con puro PHP y hacerlo que funcione tanto dentro como fuera de WP.

Comment: Por ejemplo, [este es un sitio que yo gestiono en WP](http://www.deiverbum.org). La página inicial es todo WP. Pero [aquí por ejemplo](http://www.deiverbum.org/padres/1), todo el contenido se gestiona desde fuera de WP y se presenta como si estuviese dentro del CMS. Y puedes construir incluso [una API](http://deiverbum.org/api/beta/visperas/20170831) totalmente independiente de WP... o cualquier otro contenido, usando la misma base de datos de WP u otra. Todo es código basado en PHP/HTML/Javascript En el caso de la API es usada para una App Android.

Comment: En primer lugar wordpress es más un [CMS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_gesti%C3%B3n_de_contenidos) que un framework. Si tu objetivo es realizar un [CRUD](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD) te recomendaría aprender a crear Plugins en Wordpress, puedes comenzar por aquí [codeplex](https://codex.wordpress.org/es:Escribiendo_un_Plugin). Saludos.